# Convert Facebook API Curl Request to Javascript for ImportJSON Function in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, json, curl, google-apps-script

I am trying to pull some Facebook Ad Insights API data into Google Sheets using the [ImportJSON Google Apps Script from Brad Jasper](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON). I am trying to do what I can to convert the cURL request options to a usable JavaScript variable as the "fetchOptions" using key/value pairs for the parameters and access token. Since they are marked for -d/--data for cURL, I tried adding them as a "payload", but because Facebook requires a GET method instead of POST, it won't read the payload.  Therefore, while the script is "working" it's pulling the Run Report ID since it's using a POST request instead of a GET request to actually fetch the data I'm wanting to retrieve.

Here's a sample of the cURL request:

```
curl -G \
-d "date_preset=last_7_days" \
-d "access_token=howdy" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/1234567890/insights"
```

Here's what I have so far in the ImportJSON Google Script function I'm trying to use:

```
function ImportJSONAdvanced(url, fetchOptions, query, parseOptions, includeFunc, transformFunc) {
  var fetchOptions = {"method": "GET", payload: {"access_token" : "howdy", "date_preset" : "last_7_days"}};
  var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchOptions);
  var object   = JSON.parse(jsondata.getContentText());

  return parseJSONObject_(object, query, parseOptions, includeFunc, transformFunc);
}
```

Note that the URL itself is passed as a parameter at the sheet cell level when using the function.

Any help in this matter is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have already confirmed that your curl command works fine.
- You want to convert the following curl command to Google Apps Script.

  ```
  curl -G \
  -d "date_preset=last_7_days" \
  -d "access_token=howdy" \
  "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/1234567890/insights"
  ```

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- When the curl command is run with `-G` and `-d "date_preset=last_7_days" -d "access_token=howdy"`, these keys and values are requested as the query parameters. So when this command is converted to Google Apps Script, these keys and values are required to be converted to the query parameters.
- Until recently, at UrlFetchApp, when `payload` is requested as GET method, I had confirmed that the values of `payload` were used as the query parameters. But now I confirmed that even when `payload` is requested as GET method using `method: "GET"`, it is requested as the POST method. I'm not sure whether this is the temporary situation. But I thought that the reason of the error might be this.

When above modification points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows and run again.

From:

```
var fetchOptions = {"method": "GET", payload: {"access_token" : "howdy", "date_preset" : "last_7_days"}};
var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchOptions);
```

To:

```
var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "?access_token=howdy&date_preset=last_7_days");
```

#### Note:

- This modified script is the same with the curl command. But if the error occurs, please confirm the URL, access token and other parameters, again. About these parameters, I'm not sure about the correct values. I apologize for this situation.

#### Reference:

- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

If I misunderstood your question and the result was not what you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. The only modification I had to make was to leave the GET method in the fetchOptions. So it became `var fetchOptions = {"method": "GET"}` and then used the parameters as part of the URL query string as you stated.

Comment: @Kevin Hemphill Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.